# What's the difference between Chocolatey's Git packages?

Tags: chocolatey

[Chocolatey's package repository](https://chocolatey.org/packages) shows two popular packages for installing Git:

- https://chocolatey.org/packages/git
- https://chocolatey.org/packages/git.install

What's the difference between these two packages?  How does one decide whether to use:

```
choco install git
```

or:

```
choco install git.install
```

Is one a superset of the other?

Comment: related question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/29828624/6908282

Answer (score 27, accepted):

According to [this forum thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/chocolatey/git.install/chocolatey/VwwyofMMwgs/4Zz4Q-E7qNwJ) the `.install` suffix is a discoverability artefact.  Just use the shorter name:

```
choco install git
```

Comment: Rob's longer answer on the subject: http://devlicio.us/blogs/rob_reynolds/archive/2012/02/25/chocolatey-guidance-on-packaging-apps-with-both-an-install-and-executable-zip-option.aspx

Comment: And that answer is now at http://ferventcoder.com/archive/2012/02/25/chocolatey---guidance-on-packaging-apps-with-both-an-install.aspx (although some of the guidance is older).

Answer (score 13):

Straight from their FAQ page:

https://chocolatey.org/faq#what-is-the-difference-between-packages-no-suffix-as-compared-to-install-portable

> Chocolatey has the concept of virtual packages (coming) and meta
>   packages. Virtual packages are packages that represent other packages
>   when used as a dependency. Metapackages are packages that only exist
>   to provide a grouping of dependencies.
>
> A package with no suffix that is surrounded by packages with suffixes
>   is to provide a virtual package. So in the case of git, git.install,
>   and git.commandline (deprecated for .portable) – git is that virtual
>   package (currently it is really just a metapackage until the virtual
>   packages feature is complete). That means that other packages could
>   depend on it and you could have either git.install or git.portable
>   installed and you would meet the dependency of having git installed.
>   That keeps Chocolatey from trying to install something that already
>   meets the dependency requirement for a package.
>
> Talking specifically about the `*.install` package suffix – those are
>   for the packages that have a native installer that they have bundled
>   or they download and run.
>
> **NOTE**: the suffix `*.app` has been used previously to mean the same as `*.install`. But the `*.app` suffix is now deprecated and should
>   not be used for new packages.
>
> The `*.portable` packages are the packages that will usually result in
>   an executable on your path somewhere but do not get installed onto the
>   system (Add/Remove Programs). Previously the suffixes `*.tool` and
>   `*.commandline` have been used to refer to the same type of packages.
>
> **NOTE**: now `*.tool` and `*.commandline` are deprecated and should not be used for new packages.

Want more information? See http://ferventcoder.com/archive/2012/02/25/chocolatey---guidance-on-packaging-apps-with-both-an-install.aspx