# What are all the duplicate .install packages in chocolatey package manager?

Tags: choco

What are all the duplicate .install packages in chocolatey package manager? Is one for local user and the other is for the system or something else?

```
nodejs|16.14.2|17.9.0|false
nodejs.install|16.14.2|17.9.0|false
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's a Chocolatey "Install" package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29828624/whats-a-chocolatey-install-package)